# Serial.print() Inferferes with my digitalRead()

Tags: button, debounce

I'm running into issue properly reading a button connected to a digital I/O pin on my Adafruit Feather HUZZAH ESP8266 device.

I've implemented the debouncing script exactly as the Arduino provided example shows, but if I add a print statement to my setup loop:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(230400);
  Serial.println("Starting");
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}
```

I trigger a reading of the switch on every reset cycle. Commenting out the print statement will avoid the problem so it doesn't appear to be related to the debouncing script.

In addition, I can replicate the problem on *any* digital I/O pin even when there is no pin connected. Once I get past the setup function, everything works as intended. Here's my whole setup code (again, copied from the example):

```
const int buttonPin = 13;
int buttonState;             
int lastButtonState = LOW;   

unsigned long lastDebounceTime = 0;  
unsigned long debounceDelay = 50;    

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(230400);
  Serial.println("Starting");
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  lastDebounceTime = millis(); 

}

void loop() {
  int reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if (reading != lastButtonState) {
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }

  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {
    if (reading != buttonState) {
      buttonState = reading;

      Serial.println("A");
    }
  }

  lastButtonState = reading;
}
```

And here's the output of my serial monitor (with no delays on reset):

```
Starting
A
```

I can avoid this by just ignoring the first button switch but it seems odd that this is happening and I can't find any explanations for what's going on.

Comment: Please not just include your setup code, but the whole code.

Comment: We can't either since we can't see your code ;) There's no particular reason writing to the serial port would "trigger a button read". However: serial writes are asynchronous, and adding a call to `Serial.println` adds to (a) time spent in `setup`, and (b) time spent doing "things" before the serial buffer is written out. It seems more likely there's a flaw in the debounce logic, *particularly* if `lastDebounceTime` is initialized to `0` (a Long Time Ago to the controller).

Comment: Added my loop code. @DaveNewton - I changed my setup to reset my lastDebounceTime to my last operation before entering my loop but still I print "A" on every reset.

Comment: Did you try moving the pinMode to avoid the period of floating?

Comment: I've tried putting it first and last in my setup with no effect. Would there be a time period needed for the digital read to "settle" or something?

Comment: The issue ended up that buttonState was never initialized in the example scripts so it begins != to the reading thus triggering as soon as the timer exceeds the debounce delay.  I was able to fix it simply by initializing the value to be the same as the value of lastButtonState.

Comment: I haven't really been paying much attention to this question; I just notice you've solved your own problem.  If what you've written above is an answer that follows from the information in the question and you think all of this would be useful to someone else, you can post your own answer to it.  Otherwise the question will likely float around in the system forever as unaswered, unless you delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialise `buttonState` to the current signal state and initialise `lastDebounceTime` to the current time, something like this:

```cpp
int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
unsigned long lastDebounceTime = millis();
```

Compare with this very simple [debouncer](http://github.com/TimMathias/Arduino-Debouncer) I put on GitHub.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I'm not sure why I didn't catch that or why the Arduino provided sketch doesn't initialize the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing my buttonState solved my problem:

```
int buttonState = LOW;
```

Comment: In any case, be aware that writing in serial pauses the microcontroller for a few milliseconds!

Comment: @alessandromrc: For a few microseconds. Unless the TX buffer is full, in which case it can indeed take milliseconds.

Comment: @EdgarBonet You are right!